# How can I remove every column in a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, is there a way to drop every field in my table, short of using:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
    DROP COLUMN d1,
    DROP COLUMN d1,
    etc....
```

Almost like TRUNCATE for fields maybe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll get an error when you try to drop the last column:

```
ERROR 1090 (42000): You can't delete all columns with ALTER TABLE; use DROP TABLE instead
```

Says it all!  There's no way to have a table with zero columns.

Comment: So in other words it might be easier just to recreate the table once I know which fields I need?

Comment: Got it, thanks! I don't know what I was thinking when I thought a table with no columns could exist.

Answer (score 9):

`DROP TABLE table`