# MySQL Drop Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to drop multiple columns, but having some trouble. The syntax below works when I do `ALTER TABLE` and `ADD` with multiple values in the brackets `()` but it doesn't work with `DROP COLUMN`. Am I using the wrong syntax?

```
    $table3 = "
        ALTER TABLE $table3_name
        DROP COLUMN (
            user_firstname,
            user_lastname,
            user_address,
            user_address2,
            user_city,
            user_state,
            user_zip,
            user_phone
        );
    ";
```

Comment: There is no a such syntax in the documentation, you must use something like `ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d;`

Comment: It seems like the answer was in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3894789).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I DROP multiple columns with a single ALTER TABLE statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346120/how-do-i-drop-multiple-columns-with-a-single-alter-table-statement)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
DROP `column1`,
DROP `column2`,
DROP `column3`;
```

Comment: This is what I tried next and it worked. Just thought it was odd how the other syntax didn't work when it works for other queries. Thanks.

Comment: @CoryNickerson Dropping is different from other functions such as select & replace for example

Comment: No problem, don't forget to have back-ups, though :)

Comment: A more concise way can be found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346120/how-do-i-drop-multiple-columns-with-a-single-alter-table-statement

Comment: @10basetom In the answer you linked the syntax for MySQL was the same as this one. The more concise form was non-MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

To drop multiple columns actual syntax is

```
alter table tablename drop column col1, drop column col2 , drop column col3 ....
```

So for every column you need to specify "drop column" in Mysql 5.0.45. This is same as that of above answer. Just adding one point here. Alter table wont free up the actual space on the disk. So run optimize table on after running optimize table.

Comment: The word "column" is optional.