# Is there SQL Query for excluding a single column?

Tags: sql

I was reading SQL queries and got stuck with a doubt. Is there any SQL query to exclude a single column while using select statement?

For example, I have a table which contains data about student (`s_name`, `address`, `email_id`, ..... many more).

I want to select all the columns except `email_id`.

Comment: just select  expiicittally all the other column but not email_id

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's good habit to have a `static` result set. When you use the selected data lateron - how would you deal with a newly added column? Would that work for every possible datatype that it could possibly be? What if the new column - that is *not* `email_id` should be excluded as well. 
I had the exact same thoughts like you might have, but my final conclusion was that it totally makes sense to explicitly select the columns I want to include.

Comment: You should get a decent IDE for writing your select queries which will auto populate a `SELECT` statement with all the field names, then you can remove those you don't need. Have a look at Toad (which I think works with a number of different servers) or if you are using SQL Server try RedGate's SQL Prompt (expensive but worth it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it directly in a Select statement. But you can use this alternative:

[How to select all the columns of a table except one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095281/how-to-select-all-the-columns-of-a-table-except-one-column)

Comment: If it's a duplicate, flag it as such. Don't answer simply to include a link to another question.