# How to NOT select a column for MySQL table, does it make faster query

Tags: mysql

I need to make a MySQL query where I don't want to select a column named description. Is there an easy way to specifically say to NOT select the column.

Example:
I want to **SELECT all but the description column**. Can this be done or I have to write each one I need to pick instead?

```
id| Serverid | date_added | description ...
 1        yes   12.03.09     bad engine
 3        yes   12.04.09     ok engine
 2        no    12.05.09     ok engine
 4        yes   12.06.09     bad engine



$cars = lib::$db->GetAll("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                c.*,
            FROM cars AS c
            ORDER c.date_added DESC
            LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all the columns of a table except one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095281/how-to-select-all-the-columns-of-a-table-except-one-column)

Comment: On a side note, what makes a **MUCH slower** query is  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Comment: @YourCommonSense Whats better alternative?

Comment: It depends on what you need from this number

Comment: @YourCommonSense I need to get a rows number from which I then show pages of results with a load more button.

Comment: *The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS() function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a future MySQL version.* - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: A separate select count(*) query would do

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN1), '<Col To Omit>,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TableName>' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DBName>'), ' FROM <TableName>');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Do not plagiarize existing answers

Comment: I have recently used it so can's share if someone ask for help

Answer (score -2):

**No, there is no sane way** to do that except listing all fields manually, like

```
SELECT id, Serverid, date_added FROM table
```

On a side note, with any sensible setup, there would be **no difference** in performance if you do `SELECT *`

Comment: If `description` contains a gigabyte of data per row, there will definitely be a difference in performance.

Comment: "with any *sensible* setup"

Comment: It's quite possible that the column contains a lot of data, which is why OP wants to elide it.

Comment: It makes a difference when using column types like text who's data is stored internally in an extra table requiring doing more scans!

Comment: @YourCommonSense It is extra work for the database and depending on the indexes, where conditions and table size it can make significant differences in performance. Using a Select * is more work than specifying single columns.